# Brand new Grout repair dried darker than existing brand new grout

Tags: repair, kitchens, floor, grout

I have a tile floor that was installed 2 weeks ago. There are a few spots that we needed to repair the grout. I scraped out the grout About 1/2 way down or more and replaced it with the same exact brand and color and it has dried darker in color. Dark enough that it still looks wet. This is the 3rd time I have tried this and still the same result. Can anyone tell me why it is doing this? Thanks

Comment: Is it ready mixed grout, or do you have to add water? Is it possible you're adding a different amount of water to when you made the original batch? Alternatively, is it possible that the grout colour changes over the first couple of weeks as it cures?

Answer (score 1):

Few things are perfect in this world, and that includes grout. Some variables:

- Dye lot: Factory mixes can vary by batch due to variations in color compounds
- Water content: A substantial difference is the water quantity between the original grout and yours could affect color
- Water contamination: Do you have iron or other minerals in your water? Was the bucket clean?
- Age: It's possible that a longer cure time will result in a lighter color